# Cannot use already installed Perl Module on cPanel

Tags: perl, cpanel, perl-module

I have already successfully installed the Perl module Crypt::CBC on cPanel.
But when adding the line "use Crypt::CBC;" I am getting the error:

Can't locate Crypt/CBC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at sagepay.pl line 128.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sagepay.pl line 128.

Did I miss something? Quite new to Perl modules installation.

Comment: Please [edit] the full error message into your question.

Comment: Just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with the module being installed or not. It means that something is trying to access the image file comsys_w.gif, but it doesn't exist at that location.

Comment: Yup sorry my bad! Those 404 images are from the custom error page. The actual error when I am adding "use Crypt::CBC;" is not being logged at all.

Comment: It most likely is being logged, but it might be going to a different log file. Add `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to the top of your script and fatal errors should be reported in your browser when you access the page.

Comment: Finally got the error now, updated the question! How come it cannot locate the file that was already installed? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you install Crypt::CBC? Are you sure the installation was successful? What command did you run to install it?

Comment: I installed it through the cPanel web portal. Yes it did installed successfully and appears on the Installed Modules list. 

I did try to add "use lib '/data01/c1501978/perl';" because it is the Module Include Path but still cannot locate.

Comment: @john: What command did you run to install the module?

Comment: @Borodin: I installed it through cPanel's web portal, I did not used any linux command.

Comment: `/data01/c1501978/perl` was NOT added, as you can see in by its absense from the error message. First of all, what's the output of `find /data01/c1501978/perl -name CBC.pm`

Answer (score 1):

check the value of @INC by running this using your web server:

```
 perl -e 'print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n" . join(":",@INC);'
```

`@INC` is where perl looks for modules. Perhaps they got installed in the wrong location. 
You can add new locations with perl's `-I` option (see "man perlrun" for details)

Comment: Check the value on shell right? Sorry I am new to this. I only have cPanel access.

cPanel says "Module Include Path: /data01/c1501978/perl"

Comment: No, if you `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";` before the print I gave earlier you can run it as a CGI to see what `@INC` contains when your script is executed using the webserver.

Comment: Thanks! Got this:

/data01/c1501978/perl
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8

It should work right since cPanel says that "/data01/c1501978/perl" is the Module Include Path?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may have added the module to cPanel instead of to the system Perl, for which you need to use WHM. Take a look at [these instructions](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Perl+Module+Installation) and follow the directions headed ***Install modules to the system Perl binary***

Comment: I already installed it on WHM "Software & Services > Perl Modules".
I checked and saw the file on "perl/usr/lib/perl5/Crypt". Correct right?

Comment: @john: I'm not sure about the `perl` at the start. Do you mean `/usr/lib/perl5/Crypt`, so you have a file `/usr/lib/perl5/Crypt/CBC.pm`?

Comment: I have this on the path of the file manager "/perl/usr/lib/perl5/Crypt/CBC.pm".

Comment: @john: That's a strange path, but you should be able to get it working if you add `use lib '/perl/usr/lib/perl5'` before your `use Crypt::CBC`. Is there also a `/data01/c1501978/perl/Crypt/CBC.pm`?

Comment: Hi guys this is already resolved. Thanks for the help! See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! Just a wrong path, I used this and it now works:

use lib '/data01/c1501978/perl/usr/lib/perl5';